# How to send unique value to function from onClick in a mapping loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, mapping, setstate

I am learning React. I have an array in my state which I am mapping through to render each value of the array on its own button. When the user clicks one of those buttons, I want to call a function to show some info specific to that button (the button represents a specific customer order). I tried to set state in the onClick event, but I got an 'Maximum update depth exceeded' error. If there is a way to set state from the onClick, that would solve my problem as I could just set the value of    item    of the particular button clicked to state and use it later. My other thought is to send the item to the showInfo function...however, I don't even know if that is possible. How can I call the same function from this list of buttons, and make the outcome unique to the button?

```
showInfo = (e) => {

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.showAllOrders();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello from past orders!!!</h1>
                <ul id="orderList">
                {this.state.orderDates.map((item =>
                    <li><button onClick={this.showInfo} key={item}>{item}</button></li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **an inline arrow function** as a callback to your onClick and pass the data you want.

```js
...
showInfo = (item) => {
   console.log(item);
}
...
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello from past orders!!!</h1>
            <ul id="orderList">
            {this.state.orderDates.map((item =>
                <li><button onClick={() => this.showInfo(item)} key={item}>{item}</button></li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
```

Also, never setState in your render method and thats why you got `max depth error` in your earlier try.

Comment: I have learned that setting state in the render method could cause for infinite loops. However, why would that be the case if it is housed in an onClick event, as the setState would not happen upon rendering, but upon clicking?

Comment: You may have executed the setState immediately and not in a function like

`onClick={this.setState({item: item})}`

Answer (score 1):

You could provide the function `showInfo` with info about the button via params.

So that it would be `onClick={() => this.showInfo(item)}`